# Can a warlock combine an essence into hellfire blast?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

Can a warlock combine essence invocations into Hellfire Blast such as Frightful Blast? If so, how would that change effective caster level of the blast?

Answer (score 0):

While A_S00 is correct that there is no specific reference made to hellfire blast being an essence, there are some context clues that it is.

For example, all essence invocations rename the eldritch blast using a similar pattern. Additionally, all essence invocations explicitly change the effects of being hit by the eldritch blast without changing its targeting mechanics. Additionally, there's no mention in the description of it being used with another essence invocation as there is with it being used with a blast shape invocations.

If it is not an Eldritch essence invocation, and you were to apply an Eldritch essence invocation to it, then what would the name of the resultant ability be? What type of damage would an utterdark hellfire blast do? The (already shakey) rules can break down in this situation.